# How to create an independent Fundraising Page in CiviCRM

Tags: civicrm

I am new to CiviCRM and need to create a fundraising page. I am using CiviCRM with Drupal7. As per my limited knowledge of CiviCRM, Individual users can create their Personal Campaign Pages to support different Events. But is it possible for users to create an entirely independent Fundraising page that allows them to fundraise for a particular cause and collect donations? Something like "START YOUR CAMPAIGN" tab on http://my.charitywater.org website. if Yes, How is that done?

Any Help Much Appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to create a "normal" contribution page that is the cause you want to collect money for, and enable the personal campaign pages on it.

You can make this "root" contribution page as generic and abstract as you want and let your supporters create their fundraising pages how they want it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You probably want them to be able to create a full Contribution page for that. If you are offering this to front end users you probably want to make a custom interface for it using Drupal and automatically create the contribution page in the background using the API etc. Other people have done this type of thing in the past but I not sure if any that work is public. I suggest you ask on the CiviCRM forums.